# заход на сайт робота гугл

Tags: php, google-search

Гугл исправно перебирал URL адреса на моем сайте. Но, почему то, с недавних пор, начал переходить по URL типа

```
https://mysite.ru/tovar/ÐÐÐÐÐÐ
```

Сам думал, что в сайте ссылки неправильные, или sitemap.xml запорот. но нет. Возникает вопрос, откуда кракозябры идут, и как от них избавляться?

P.S. кодировка файла и в файле UFT-8, англ. адреса при переборе - норм, русские идут кракозябрами.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спустя 3 недели ( к сожалению путем проб и ошибок  ) переделал кодировку файла на 8859, и о чудо карокозябр нету. Если кто сталкнется с таким - пробуйте! Конкретно в моем случае прокатило